# railsでviewファイルを動的に切り替えたい

Tags: ruby-on-rails

スマホからアクセスした時にスマホ用にビューを切り替えたいのですが、やり方がわかりません。

`post/edit.html.erb`
↓
`post/sp_edit.html.erb`

このように接頭語を付与する形が理想です。
スマホ用のビューがなかったら通常のビューファイルを使うということができれば完璧です。

どこにどのように記述するのがよろしいでしょうか。

Answer (score 3):

1. ActionPack Variantsを使う
   Controllerのbefore_actionでrequest.variantをセットしてください。
   メリット：RoRのフレームワーク機能なので導入で揉めることが少ないです。
   デメリット：ファイル名規則が綺麗とはいえません。それから階層的な探索する(ファイルが無ければより大枠での別viewを探す)ことも後述のjpmobileと比べて細かくありません。
2. jpmobileを使う
   Controllerにinclude Jpmobile::ViewSelectorをセットしてください。
   メリット：gemの中で勝手にやってくれるので分岐意識が不要になります。
   デメリット：sp_edit.html.erbという命名規則が実現できないぐらいです。
3. 自分でラッパーなりを書く
   1つ1つヘルパーなり何なりをシコシコと書くしかないので割愛します。
   メリット：sp_edit.html.erbの命名規則は間違いなく担保できる
   デメリット：partialみたいに明示的に書くならいいのでしょうが。controllerのrenderみたいに省略されている場合などもアレコレと各必要があって、私は保守の観点からお勧めできません。

個人的には「スマホ用のビューがなかったら通常のビューファイルを使うということができれば完璧」という点を考えてもjpmobileの使用をオススメします。
jpmobileが採用しにくい理由があれば。それを質問文に追記してください。

Answer (score 1):

Rails 4.1以降であれば、[Action Pack Variants](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/4_1_release_notes.html#action-pack-variants)を使うといいと思います。

コントローラで`request.variant`を設定します。

`app/controllers/foos_controller.rb`

```ruby
class FoosController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_variant, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  def set_variant
    if smart_phone?
      request.variant = :sp
    end
  end
```

スマホ用のviewでは`html+sp.erb`のように`request.variant`に指定した名前を`+`でつけます。

例: `app/views/foos/edit.html+sp.erb`

設定したvariant用のviewがない場合は、variantなしのviewがrenderされます。